# How should I reset a user's password?

Tags: solidity, truffle

So I'm making a dapp. This portion uses smart contract for login. I need to add the ability to reset the user's password if they forget it.

```
contract Auth {
struct Credentials {
    string fullName;
    string email;
    string password;
}

mapping(string => Credentials) credential;

function createAccount(
    string memory name,
    string memory pass,
    string memory mail
) public {
    credential[mail].fullName = name;
    credential[mail].email = mail;
    credential[mail].password = pass;
}

function loginAccount(string memory mail, string memory pass)
    public
    view
    returns (string memory)
{
    if (
        keccak256(abi.encodePacked(credential[mail].password)) ==
        keccak256(abi.encodePacked(pass))
    ) {
        return
            string(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    credential[mail].fullName,
                    credential[mail].email
                )
            );
    } else {
        return "Wrong Password";
    }
}

function resetAccount(string memory mail) public {
    //reset acc
}
```

Sorry I have no idea where to go with this.

Comment: Hey Julia, welcome to StackExchange! You might have misunderstood how blockhains works. [Smart contracts are not databases](https://medium.com/coinmonks/smart-contracts-are-not-databases-5bb5926223be). You should never store any private information, more especially user passwords, in an Ethereum smart contract.

Comment: In other words, anything you put a on a blockchain is public. In your case, anyone can see all the passwords for all the users.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg interesting. I'm trying to figure out how I should handle the situation, as I'm making a travel ID Dapp

Comment: Hi Julia with a Dapp you probably don't even need a password. For example  https://app.ens.domains/ only has a "Connect". https://docs.metamask.io/guide/getting-started.html#basic-considerations 
Paul and others may know good tutorials for this.